# Flask and Working outside of application context

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, flask

I am testing a simple slack command, which is supposed to return a response upon invocation and then start a new thread where it will calculate new response and post it back. However, it seems like there is no way to call `jsonify` inside the thread, because if do that, it throws : `RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.`

```
from flask import abort, Flask, jsonify, request
import requests
import json
from dateutil.parser import parse
from threading import Thread


def backgroundworker(somedata,response_url):

    payload = jsonify(
                  response_type='in_channel',
                  text="test"
              )

    requests.post(response_url,data=json.dumps(payload))    

@app.route('/appmethodaddress',methods=['POST','GET'])
def receptionist():

    response_url = request.form.get("response_url")

    somedata = {}

    thr = Thread(target=backgroundworker, args=[somedata,response_url])
    thr.start()

    return jsonify(message= "working on your request")
```

Is there an easy way to call `jsonify` inside `backgroundworker` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to make a json out of it, use json.dumps() method (https://kite.com/python/docs/json.dumps).